# How can I display vertical lines to align tags in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In demos online, I frequently see people in VS 2008 with vertical lines between the opening and closing tags of their HTML, or between curly braces in C#.  This makes it easy to find both tags in a block.  I can't figure out how to set that up.  Perhaps it's a 3rd party plug-in?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about in HTML files, but in C# files you can get this with [CodeRush Xpress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/dd218053.aspx) which is free.

Comment: I was just about to suggest that, it's what I use and it does exactly what's described!

Comment: Thanks.  This would explain why I could find no relevant setting in VS alone, since it's a 3rd party add-on.